# Basic F# / Entity Framework / Generic Functions

Tags: entity-framework, generics, f#, crud

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to development, so apologies in advance for my poor grasp of the terminology here...

I'm trying to create a number of very simple unrelated tables in a SQL database just to get my head round things. I'd like to reference these using Entity Framework, and I'd like to minimise repetition where possible. I'm trying to understand whether there is a more elegant way of doing this so that I don't have to re-write the getters and setters each time:

```
// First open "System; System.Data; System.Data.Entity; System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" 
// Then define "connectionString"
// Then create two simple classes that have no relation to each other, using CLIMutable 
// to help Entity Framework along.

module Model = 
    [<CLIMutable>] type Customer = {[<Key>]Id: int; FirstName: string; LastName: string;}
    [<CLIMutable>] type Item = {[<Key>]Id: int; ItemName: string; ItemDescription: string;}

module Actions =
    open Model
    type Context() =
        inherit DbContext()

        [<DefaultValue>] val mutable customers: DbSet<Customer> 
            member public this.Customers with get() = this.customers
                                           and  set v = this.customers <- v

        [<DefaultValue>] val mutable items: DbSet<Item>
            member public this.Items with get() = this.items
                                           and  set v = this.items <- v

// I would like to be able to add several more very simple classes without having to 
// repetively type out the getters and setters each time. Ideally I'd like to turn the above 
// into a generic function (method? I'm not sure of terminology) that I can call later and 
// pass it my desired parameters in terms of table/object names. However, if I move the code 
// above the Model and replace DbSet<Customer> with DbSet<'T> this won't work since it won't 
// know what type 'T is at this point. I suspect I need a generic function (method?) that 
// I can create a new instance of later and replace the generics with actual values (using 
// reflection?). Is there any way to do this without making Entity Framework get upset?

    let db = new Context()
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString <- Settings.connectionString
```

Similarly I'd like to create a generic function that does the Add() and SaveChanges() steps 
below, but I'm not sure whether this is possible since I'd need to dynamically replace 
'Customers' or 'Items' with a table name that I've passed in - and also the type of 't' 
could vary depending on what is calling the function and I don't know whether that's allowed.

```
    let createCustomer id firstName lastName = 
        let t : Customer = {Id = id;FirstName = firstName; LastName = lastName}
        db.Customers.Add(t) |> ignore
        db.SaveChanges() |> ignore

    let createItem id itemName itemDescription = 
        let t : Item = {Id = id; ItemName = itemName; ItemDescription = itemDescription}
        db.Items.Add(t) |> ignore
        db.SaveChanges() |> ignore

open Actions
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =     
    createCustomer 1 "Bob" "Smith"
    createItem 1 "First item" "First item test"

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Thanks for any help, understand my questions are probably very basic so if people can't be bothered to re-write code but are able to point me in the right direction of resources for further reading that'd be great!

[edit] Thanks very much to Fyodor for providing the solution. The key was adding the ": Context" type annotation to the "db" element when referring to it generally. Additionally I had made the silly mistake of not opening the "Model" module in my main argument. Updated and working code it as below:

```
module Model = 
    [<CLIMutable>] type Customer = {[<Key>]Id: int; FirstName: string; LastName: string;}

module Actions =
    open Model
    type Context() =
        inherit DbContext()
        member val Customers: DbSet<Customer> = null with get, set

    let db = new Context()
    db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString <- Settings.connectionString

    let addAndCommit (db : Context) x =
        db.Set().Add x |> ignore
        db.SaveChanges() |> ignore

    let createCustomer id firstName lastName = 
        addAndCommit db {Id = id; FirstName = firstName; LastName = lastName}

open Actions
open Model
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =     
    createCustomer 1 "Bob" "Smith"
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First,** to declare a property with a backing field, use `member val`:

```
type Context() =
    ...
    member val Customers: DbSet<Customer> = null with get, set
    ...
```

**Second,** to access a `DbSet` of a specific type, you don't need a property. You can get it via `DbContext.Set<'t>` method:

```
let addAndCommit (db: Context) (x: 't) =
    db.Set<'t>().Add x |> ignore
    db.SaveChanges() |> ignore

let createCustomer id firstName lastName = 
    addAndCommit db {Id = id; FirstName = firstName; LastName = lastName}
```

But the explicit `'t` annotation is not really required: F# can infer it for you.

```
let addAndCommit (db: Context) x =
    db.Set().Add x |> ignore
    db.SaveChanges() |> ignore
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking a look Fyodor. I tried something like that last night but couldn't get it working and I'm still struggling. I've updated my original question - I get red squiggles below 'db.Set()' and 'db.SaveChanges()' due to "Lookup on object of indeterminate type...".

Comment: That's because F# can't infer the type of `db` based solely on methods you're calling on it. You need a type annotation.

Comment: Also, "getting red squigglies` is not a good description of a problem. In the future, try to provide full information about the specific problems you face. That way you have a better chance to get help.

Comment: Thanks Fyodor. I guessed that was what I need to do, however I don't know how to do it. So my question is, how do I add a type annotation? Please understand that for me, a complete beginner, describing it as 'red squigglies' and including the error message I get is my way of ensuring I stay accurate. I could have said "the F# compiler complains" or "intellisense suggests I have made a mistake" but I don't know which is more accurate, so I describe what I see. It won't build, that's all I know ;)

Comment: See my answer for how to do the type annotation.

Comment: I've updated the code, copy and pasting your example but unfortunately I'm still unable to get it working. I've pasted the exact code towards the end of my original question. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: "Can't get it working" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: Argh I'm an idiot! It's because I wasn't opening the 'Model' module within the 'main' bit of the code. All sorted now. I'll update my original question with the working code. Thanks again!

Comment: "Can't it get working" was backed up with a full description of the error message: "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed prior to this program point to constrain the type of object. This may allow the lookup to be resolved." Please go easy on me I'm a complete novice ;)